# Display twitter name and avatar in meteor app

Tags: meteor, twitter, ionic-framework

Im building and app using meteor and ionic and i want to display the name and the avatar of the user logged in. 
I wrote this

```
<img src="{{Meteor.users().services.twitter.profile_image_url}}">
```

but it is not working. The same query in my console returns the right result. Is it becaus i removed autopublish ? Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a helper then use it for the URL

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
    imageUrl: function(){
        return Meteor.user().services.twitter.profile_image_url;
        //you wrote Meteor.users() which should be user()
    }
});
```

Then use it in your HTML

```
<img src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

**EDIT:**

Meteor.user() will return the current user object. If you want the user's profile picture to be visible somewhere to other users or even if that user is not logged in, you should store user's id and use that id to find & return user object or some specific data. For example, if you have a posts collection, you can do the following...

```
//inside your insert post method, save userId
owner: this.userId

//usage in template helper where you have the post data
userObj: function(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner) //returns user object.
}

//HTML

{{userObj.someData}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To overcome removal of autopublish you can publish your collection data in a server javascript file and subscribe to same collection in a client javascript file.

Also you can do the following for your own image collections, better implementation in my point of view:

in a HTML file where you get your userId from router:

```
<img src="{{getUserProfileImage userId}}">
```

in a client javascript file like common.js

```
Template.registerHelper('getUserProfileImage', function(userId) {
        return UserImages.findOne({userId: userId}).image;
    }
});
```

You should better store each image in a collection like I did. Also using Meteor.user() directly may cause errors if user hasn't logged-in.

Please add javascript tag to your codes for formatting.